# PHP-MYSQLI : My login scripts logs direct users into the same page

Tags: php, mysql, session, mysqli, authentication

For the most part, my website logins perfectly!
i can happily verify the users email when they login to their account, but I was just testing my login page, and realised different users are being directed to the exactly the same page, no matter their email address or password and are able to gain access to other users information. What can i do to resolve this?

Is there any way of checking both the email address and AccountId when they login to the accounts page?

PHP LOGIN PAGE

```
         if (isset($_POST['login']))

        //database varianbles
            $c_email = $_POST['email'];
        $c_password = $_POST['pass1'];


        // select login details
        $sel_c = "SELECT * FROM Cus_Register WHERE Cus_Email='$c_email' AND Cus_Password='$c_password'";

        $run_c = mysqli_query($dbc, $sel_c);
        //check if customer is on databse
        $check_customer = mysqli_num_rows($run_c);




        if ($check_customer == 0) {
            echo "password or email is incorrect please try again";
            exit();
          } else {
            session_start();
            $_SESSION['Cus_Email'] = $c_email;

  //                echo "<script> alert ('Logged in successfully')</script>";
            echo "<script>window.open('./customer/Cus_Account.php','_self')      </script>";
            exit();
        }
        ?>
```

CUSTOMERS ACCOUNTS PAGE

```
 session_start();
 //if user is not logged re-direct them to login page
 if (isset($_SESSION['Cus_Email'])) {

} else {
 //    header("Location: ./login.php");
echo "<script>window.open('../login.php','_self')</script>";
}
 ?>
```

Cus_Reg Table

```
  CREATE TABLE `Cus_Register` (
 `Cus_Email` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
 `Cus_Password` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
 `Cus_confirm_Password` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
 `AccountID` tinyint(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 PRIMARY KEY (`AccountID`),
 UNIQUE KEY `Cus_Email` (`Cus_Email`)
 ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=3 DEFAULT CHARSET=outfit
```

SELECT INFO

```
<?php
$details = $dbc->query("SELECT * FROM Cus_acc_details");
$cus_dets = $details->fetch_array(MYSQLI_BOTH);

//session_start does not work here 

$_SESSION['fname'] = $cus_dets['CUS_Fname'];
$_SESSION['lname'] = $cus_dets['Cus_Lname'];
$_SESSION['phone'] = $cus_dets['CUS_Phone'];
$_SESSION['CustomerID'] = $cus_dets['CustomerID'];
?>
```

Comment: show how you select the details to show on the customers account page

Comment: @dragon i have just updated the post

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need to specify which row to `SELECT`, your query currently selects all the rows, thus they can see other users' information.

There isn't anything to change in CUSTOMERS ACCOUNTS PAGE since there isn't any query taking place.

Your code in SELECT INFO page should be:

```
session_start();

$c_email = $_SESSION['Cus_Email'];

$details = $dbc->query("SELECT * FROM Cus_acc_details WHERE Cus_Email = '$c_email'");
$cus_dets = $details->fetch_array(MYSQLI_BOTH);

$_SESSION['fname'] = $cus_dets['CUS_Fname'];
$_SESSION['lname'] = $cus_dets['Cus_Lname'];
$_SESSION['phone'] = $cus_dets['CUS_Phone'];
$_SESSION['CustomerID'] = $cus_dets['CustomerID'];
```

---

Also, in your LOGIN PAGE, you should prevent MySQL Injection using `mysqli_real_escape_string()`:

```
$c_email = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, $_POST['email']);
$c_password = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, $_POST['pass1']);
```

---

**Just a tip:** You shouldn't store users' passwords as plain-text, you should hash/ crypt it.

In PHP 5.5, there's a Password Hash function: http://php.net/manual/en/ref.password.php.

Comment: Thank you so much. My code was exactly like this at one stage and i deleted it

Comment: @jerneva You're welcome! Glad to have solved your problem :)

Comment: i am having the same issue with another login page, but this method does not seem to work on that login. instead i am getting a fatal error message, do you have any ideas why

Comment: @jerneva There's quite many possibilities, try to turn on Error Reporting